# Can anyone help me reduce the execution time of my python code

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

The time limit is 4000ms, but the input is so big that the execution time limit is exceeded. Can anyone show me where and how to optimize my code. The task is:

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is
>   possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more
>   than one element from the array.

Thank you in advance.

PS: This task is also available on CodeFights.

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence): # The main function
    for x in range(0,len(sequence)):
         copyOfSequence = copySequence(sequence)
         del copyOfSequence[x]
         if checkSequence(copyOfSequence) == True:
             return True
    return False

def copySequence(sequence):    # Create a sequence that is the same with input
    copyOfSequence = sequence[::]
    return copyOfSequence

#Check if the sequence is a strictly increasing sequence when I remove a element
def checkSequence(sequence):
    for i in range(0, len(sequence) - 1):
        if sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]: return False
    return True
```

Comment: Hint: do you **really** need two nested loops for that?

Comment: Making copies and deleting elements in the middle of lists are expensive operations. Come up with an algorithm that works on the original list.

Comment: @Henry i'm new so my idea is not very good, i don't know other way to replace the function checkSequence although two nested loops will take much time

Comment: @MarkTolonen thank for your advice, i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not giving you direct code here as this problem comes from a programming arena.

If the array length is 1 then you don't need to remove any elements

else

keep `flag = 0`

loop through 1 to lenght-1 of array

1. `val =array[n]- array[n-1]`
2. if `val < 0` update `flag += 1`
3. `if flag > 1` then we need to remove at least 2 elemets.

`if flag < 2` then the given array has to delete no more than 1 element.

You don't need to copy array by [:].

Comment: This is too simple, consider 1 5 3 4 6; flag would be 1 but it is still not possible to delete only a single element.

Comment: if I delete only 5 ?

Comment: Ok, overlooked that. make it 1 4 5 2 3 6.

Answer (score 0):

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

First, take the running difference across the entire array:

```
import numpy as np
d = np.diff(a)
```

Then count how many times it is not positive:

```
c = (d <= 0).sum()
```

If c is more than 1, it's impossible.  If c is 0, it is possible.  If c is 1, find where it is:

```
i = np.where(d <= 0)[0][0]
```

Then check if removing it would satisfy the constraint:

```
a[i-1] < a[i+1]
```

Done.

In the 4 second time limit I expect you can check an array of roughly 50 million elements (400 MB of data).

Comment: Thank you very much =)) Very helpful